# document.querySelector in a discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to connect a local site with a discord.js bot
so if the thing I want to do works put it online in a server.

I want to sent in a discord server channel the value of an input.

js: src/bot/index.js

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { TOKEN } = require('./config.json');

channelid = "925049593056596009"

const client = new Client({ intents: 32767});


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

function test() {
    document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        channelid.send(document.querySelector('.input').value)
    })
}
test()
client.login(TOKEN);
```

html: src/html/application.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Applications</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="../bot/index.js"></script>

    <form>
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="say something">
        <button class="button">OK</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
   document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Comment: Can we see your files?

Comment: @Leau i am new to stack how can i send images

Comment: Don't send image, just attach your code (with file name) in codeblocks please.

Comment: ok i will edit the question

Comment: @Leau check again i edited

Comment: You can't import Discord.js like a Node.js module, import one of these webpacks https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/tree/webpack in your html file.

Comment: @Leau What do you mean? how can i do this

Comment: Those builds are outdated. Discord.js is a library for Node.js. If you want your Node application to interact with a website, you will need to expose a REST API or use WebSockets or a similar technology.

Comment: ok thanks ill use a rest api

Answer (score 0):

Add require.js to your project from this link
[require.js](https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js)

Then load discord.js and your index.js as following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Applications</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script data-main="./src/discord.js" src="./src/require.js"></script>
    <script data-main="./src/index.js" src="./src/require.js"></script>

    <form>
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="say something">
        <button class="button">OK</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Refer this documentation 

https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles